# unhandledRejection is not assignable to parameter of type Signals

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a file, `registerExceptionHandler.ts`, that does some logging in case of an unexpected crash of my application. The file looks like this:

```
const handleException = function(ex: Error): void {
  console.log('Unexpected exception occured.', { ex });

  process.exit(1);
};

export const registerExceptionHandler = function(): void {
  process.on('uncaughtException', handleException);
  process.on('unhandledRejection', handleException);
};
```

It works, but on the second `process.on` I get the following error message:

> Argument of type '"unhandledRejection"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Signals'.

Why? What am I missing?

Comment: Which version of node and @types/node are you using? I just checked in a project I have and I have both  - `unhandledRejection` and `Signals` events types: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZzi6.png

Comment: It's Node.js 10.15.3, TypeScript 3.5.3, and @types/node 12.6.8.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, I got it: The signature of the `handleException` function does not match what the `unhandledRejection` case expects.

If I change my implementation to

```
const handleException = function(ex: Error): void {
  console.log('Unexpected exception occured.', { reason: ex.message, ex });

  process.exit(1);
};

const handleRejectedPromise = function(
  reason: any,
  promise: Promise<any>
): void {
  console.log('Unexpected exception occured.', { reason, ex: promise });

  process.exit(1);
};

export const registerExceptionHandler = function(): void {
  process.on('uncaughtException', handleException);
  process.on('unhandledRejection', handleRejectedPromise);
};
```

things work as expected.